# creating circles with svg and javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

(UPDATED) I'm having some issues regarding svg and javascript. What I want to create is a series of circles on top of one another, with their radius (r) values increasing by one each time the loop goes round, so that it creates some sort of a pattern. Here is what I have so far(for loop values are from another forum post, I would rather do it with a while loop that would execute 10 times) -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Dynamic SVG!</title>
</head>
<defs>
    <svg height="10000" width="10000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
         <circle id="cir1" cx="300" cy="300" r="40" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="" fill="none"/>
</svg>
</defs>
<script>
   var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
   for (var x = 0; x < 5000; x += 50) {
       for (var y = 0; y < 3000; y += 50) {
          var circle = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'circle');
          circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', x);
          circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', y);
          circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '50');
          circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '50');
          document.getElementById('cir1').appendChild(circle);
        }
   }
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help out there?
Thanks.

Comment: You code has plenty syntax errors. I suggest you use the console to walk through your errors.

Comment: Im using Jedit to write this, thus I have not got a console to debug.

Comment: Open your page in any browser and open it developer tools (F12 for most browser nowadays). There you'll have a console, which shows you the errors.

Comment: There is no errors in this code now according to the firefox console, but nothing is coming up on screen anymore, please help, Im very confused now :(

Comment: I have found all errors and fixed them, but nothing appears on screen. Ive also found this forum post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786797/how-to-draw-rectangles-dynamically-in-svg Thats what I want to do but I would like 10 to be added to the circle radius each iteration, how would I use this for mine? Thanks.

Comment: If you fixed your code, update your question. Then we may be able to go on from there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, so this is, what I had to fix in order to get your code working:

- You append to the circle element, but should append to the svg-container. A circle element has no child elements.
- You did not set any styles for the circles, so they were transparent.
- The coordinates in a circle element are called `cx` and `cy` instead of `x` and `y`.
- The `<defs>` element should be a child of the `<svg>` element. Also everything within it wont be rendered.

**JavaScript**

```
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
    container = document.getElementById( 'cont' );
for (var x = 0; x < 500; x += 50) {
    for (var y = 0; y < 300; y += 50) {
        var circle = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'circle');
        circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', x);
        circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', y);
        circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', 50);
        circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', 'fill: none; stroke: blue; stroke-width: 1px;' );
        container.appendChild(circle);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<svg id="cont" height="1000" width="1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <circle id="cir1" cx="300" cy="300" r="40" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sirko/jKqcG/556/)

<sub>I also adjusted your sizes as for a mere test, they were quite big.</sub>

Comment: thanks! I had taken the for loop out of another example from here. How would I modify the for loop so that it does not change the position(cx,cy) of the the circle, but just changes the radius?

Comment: @user2324169 Put in constants, where you set `cx` and `cy` and set a `r` value that is changed by the loop variable.

Comment: Please note that there seems to be a small typo, the code defines a variable container but does not use it. It goes directly to the document.cont element. This does not change the solution though :-)

Comment: @JulianPollak Thanks. Fixed that nevertheless.