# Adding an SVG element to Highcharts canvas

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I would like to add, for example, a rect to a Highcharts canvas. I see that there's an SVG element inside the highcharts div, however it doesn't have an `id` so I don't know how to get a reference.

[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786797/how-to-draw-rectangles-dynamically-in-svg) it explains how to add rectangles to an SVG canvas dynamically using Javascript, I would like to add these to the Highcharts canvas, any ideas?

Comment: Could you get a reference like this: `document.getElementsByTagName("svg");`?

Comment: this is how I did it:    `var div = document.getElementsByClassName('highcharts-container')[0]; var svg = div.firstChild;`

Comment: Again, I suggest to use Highcharts API to render shapes in the SVG. [Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.arc). That renderer supports also VML.